# JQuery Replace a Modal form with another modal form

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to replace one modal form with another by clicking a href within the modal form?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this.

Html

```
<a href="#" id="launchModel1">Launch modal 1</a>

<div id="modal1" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Modal 1
     <a href="#" id="launchModel2">Launch modal 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="modal2" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Modal 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#launchModel1").bind("click", function(){
$('#modal1').modal('show');
});

$("#launchModel2").bind("click", function(){
   $('#modal1').modal('hide');
   $('#modal2').modal('show');
});
```

Working sample - http://www.bootply.com/YR7UREs1Ck

Comment: Hi, works well and answers my question! I was more thinking about the ID being got from the href so as this could be reused without hardcoding modal 2... problem seems to be in capturing the href and the modal details at the same time!!